# Class variables will not overwritten by funktions

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to read out a database for a login-portal. This part is working in a class dbreader.
The username and password will be saved in the variables cUsername and cUserpass. Before they get overwritten by a function the variables are defined as empty strings "". \

But when I try this: `username = dbreader().cUsername`, I get an empty string.

Here is the code:

```py
class dbreader:
    db_path = "Home-Tool/UserDB"
    cUsername = ""
    cUserpass = ""
    cName = ""
    id_range_bool = False
    iddb = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = _sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)
        self.c = self.connection.cursor()

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()

    def run_sqlCommand(self):
        while True:
            sqlcom = "SELECT * FROM userinfos WHERE id = " + str(self.iddb)
            self.c.execute(sqlcom)
            self.connection.commit()
            for row in self.c.fetchall():  # self.c = tuble(4)
                self.cID = str(row[0])
                self.cUsername = str(row[1])
                self.cUserpass = str(row[2])
                self.cName = str(row[3])
            if self.cUsername == cEntryUsername:
                break
            if not self.id_range_bool:
                break
            else:
                self.id_range_bool = False
            self.iddb += 1


dbreader().run_sqlCommand()

username = dbreader.cUsername
userpass = dbreader.cUserpass
name = dbreader.cName
```

Comment: Setting e.g. `self.cUsername` sets the attribute on the `self` instance, not on the class. Save the instance of `dbreader` in a variable like `dbinst=dbreader()` then operate on the instance like `dbinst.run_sqlCommand()` and you will be able to access e.g. `dbinst.cUsername`

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since `dbreader` is a class, accessing an attribute will return it as a class variable, not as an instance. The way you have it set up, `dbreader.cUsername` and `dbreader.cPassword` will never change, because nothing overwrites them.

On a particular *instance* of a `dbreader`, these attributes are overwritten. But you have to use the same instance:

```
dbreader_instance = dbreader()  # create an instance, save the instance to a variable
dbreader_instance.run_sqlCommand()

username = dbreader_instance.cUsername
userpass = dbreader_instance.cUserpass
name = dbreader_instance.cName
```

You could then create another, separate instance of `dbreader`, and it might have a different `cUsername` and `cUserpass` from the one above.